# Multi Drop Down Vertical Menu

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical drop down menu that has three levels. I cannot seem to get the third drop down to be hidden until it is hovered. Any suggestions? I know I'm missing something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the HTML:

```
<li class="family"><a href="#">Family Matters</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Adoptions</a></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Custody/Proceedings</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Child Custody Proceedings</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Protective Proceedings</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Child Protective Proceedings</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Deceased Estates</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Informal Probate</a></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Small Estates</a></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Affidavit of Successor</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Divorces</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">With Children</a></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Without Children</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Fines & Fees</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Circuit Court</a></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Circuit Ct. - Family Div.</a></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Probate Court</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Friend of the Court</a></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Guardian/Conservator</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Adult Guardian</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Adult Guardianship</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Minor Guardian</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Minor Guardianship</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Disabled Guardian</a>
<ul class="familyhover">
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Dev. Disabled Guardianship</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Adult Conservator</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="familyhover"><a href="#">Juvenile Delinquency</a></li>
</ul></li>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* Sidebar Styles */

.side-bar {
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
float:left;

}

/*main menu*/

.side-bar ul {
padding: 5px;
}

.side-bar ul li a {
color: #000;
font-size:15px;
width:225px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
}

.side-bar ul li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

.side-bar ul li:hover ul {
background-color: #FFF;
display: block;
margin-left: 150px;
margin-top: -45px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

/*first drop*/

.side-bar ul ul {
position: absolute;
margin-left: 100px;
display: none;
z-index:1;
text-align: center;
padding:0;
}

/*first drop hover*/

.side-bar li:hover ul ul {
display:none;
}

/*second drop hover*/

.side-bar li ul li:hover ul {
display:block; 
margin-top:-42px;
margin-left: 210px;
z-index:1;
text-align: center;
}
.sidebar > li.family:hover {
border-top: 3px solid #1A7208;
margin-top:-3px;

}

/*To change main nav 1st drop level background and link color for "FAMILY"*/

.sidebar > li.family ul.familyhover {
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

/*User hovers over main nav 2nd drop level link menu for "FAMILY"*/
.sidebar > li.family ul.familyhover li.familyhover a:hover {
background-color:#1A7208;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*User hovers over main nav 3rd drop level link menu for "FAMILY"*/
.sidebar > li.family ul.familyhover li.familyhover ul.familyhover a:hover {
background-color:#1A7208;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*User hovers over main nav 4th drop level link menu for "FAMILY"*/
.sidebar > li.family ul.familyhover li.familyhover ul.familyhover a:hover {
background-color:#1A7208;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yv4ogdcg/

I only posted the portion of the code that I need help on. The JSFiddle has the entire sidebar code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For me the 3rd level is hidden and then visible when hovering on a level 2 item in Chrome 43+

Comment: I'm using Safari. I haven't tested it in other browsers yet

Comment: I'm on Firefox (latest) running on Windows 8.1. They do appear only when the 2nd level menu is hovered. Are you sure you've cleared your browser cache before refreshing that page?

Comment: Maybe not....I thought I did, but I will give it a try